# R Control scientific formatting of axis numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am using ggplot to create a number of plots that have similar shape and x-axis, but for which the y axis has greatly differing values.

My problem is that some plots have y axis numbers presented in single pre-exponential digits, e.g. 2e-05, and some plots have numbers with two or more digits, e.g. 1.5e-05.

For uniformity I wish to control the exponential formatting of the y axis numbers to force all number labels to a specific number of digits, e.g. 2.0e-5.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Peter

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format` to format the labels:

```r
library(ggplot2)
a <- c(1e-5, 2.5e-4, 1.555e-3)
b <- 1:3

## No formatting
ggplot(NULL, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
## Formatted
ggplot(NULL, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=a, labels=format(a, scientific=TRUE, digits=2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>